# Cloud Function: Adding a Date Field to Table

Tags: function, datetime, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I´m using Google Cloud Funtion to create a table, for now everything works the way it is supposed to.

But I would like to add a new field in the table, one that could show the time of its creation.

This is an example of the code that I´m using at the moment.

Don´t know why Is not working but my main goal is to actually be able to do it with one table and the replicate the process in codes there I handle two or more tables.

Example:

structure of the data in the bucket:

[image]

Function

[image]

#### Code

**main**

```py
from google.cloud
import bigquery

import pandas as pd

from previsional_tables
import table_TEST1

creation_date = pd.Timestamp.now()# Here is where I´ m supposed to get the date.

def main_function(event, context):

    dataset = 'bd_clients'

file = event

input_bucket_name = file['bucket']

path_file = file['name']

uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(input_bucket_name, path_file)

path_file_list = path_file.split("/")

file_name_ext = path_file_list[len(path_file_list) - 1]

file_name_ext_list = file_name_ext.split(".")

name_file = file_name_ext_list[0]

print('nombre archivo ==> ' + name_file.upper())

print('Getting the data from bucket "{}"'.format(uri))

path_file_name = str(uri)

print("ruta: ", path_file_name)

if ("gs://bucket_test" in path_file_name):

    client = bigquery.Client()

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()

table_test1(dataset, client, uri, job_config, bigquery)
```

**tables**

```py
def table_test1(dataset, client, uri, job_config, bigquery):

    table = "test1"

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset)

job_config.autodetect = True

job_config.max_bad_records = 1000

job_config.schema = [

    bigquery.SchemaField("NAME", "STRING"),

    bigquery.SchemaField("LAST_NAME", "STRING"),

    bigquery.SchemaField("ADDRESS", "STRING"),

    bigquery.SchemaField("DATE", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.DATE)# create each column in Big Query along with types

]

job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV

job_config.field_delimiter = ';'

job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(uri, dataset_ref.table(table), job_config = job_config)
```

**requirements**

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version

google-cloud-bigquery==2.25.1

pysftp==0.2.9

pandas==1.4.2

fsspec==2022.5.0

gcsfs==2022.5.0
```

Output structure in Database:

[image]

Comment: How would you get the time of creation? Take into consideration that you cannot add a new column with a default value to an existing table. However, you can add the column without a default value, then change its default value by using the ALTER COLUMN SET DEFAULT DDL statement.

Comment: Hello and thank you. I haven´t consider create the table first and then alter it, let see if i can do it on my own.